# An error occurred while using kettle's flow control

Tags: java, kettle

As soon as I click the kettle flow control button, the kettle runs with an error.

[image]

[image]

This is the next error code when I click on the details button.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon$16.mouseMove(Spoon.java:2182)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1381)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7817)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9179)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:707)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.